# Cocos2d android sprite loading white square space

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I develop Android game with cocos2d. I load sprite in this way:

```
              CCSprite sprite = CCSprite.sprite("sprite.png");
```

The problem is that the image sometime is loaded as white square or loading wrong image,
can anyone please help me to solve this problem...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, when i am using UI Handlers within my CCLayer class the problem arrived. i just moved that to my main activity... problem solved....